# Eclipse CDT Build Configs - Testing a DLL with CPP Unit

Tags: c++, project-management, eclipse-cdt, buildconfiguration

I'm making a DLL (and probably a Linux port at some later date) in C++ using eclipse. The situation is as follows: I am trying to make two separate build configurations, one that will build a DLL and one that will build an executable CppUnit test. Currently I have all of the DLL build working, and I can make a separate project to test the DLL with; however, I was wondering if there was any way to do this all in one project.

Help on this matter would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, I found out how to do it, so if anyone else stumbles across this...

If you go into *"Project->Properties->C/C++ Build->Settings"*, then select a debug configuration (or create a new one). Go to the *"Build Artifact"* tab, and change the *"Artifact Type"* to *executable*.

Now to avoid having all of your source code compiled into all Build Configurations (such as your main() being built into a DLL, which doesn't make much sense), go to *"Project->Properties->C/C++ General->Paths and Symbols"*. Select your build configuration and go to the *"Source Location"* tab. Here you can add new source folders/remove source folders that already exist.